# Reading file and writing its content after replacing strings with new strings in python

Tags: python

I got this code below to test out but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

Note that I'm using MacM1 and use vscode as IDE.

```
fin = open("file.txt", "rt")

#output file to write the result to
fout = open("out.txt", "wt")

#for each line in the input file
for line in fin:

    #read replace the string and write to output file
    fout.write(line.replace('old', 'new'))

#close input and output files
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I've the `file.txt` ready with strings in it including `'old'`.
Once I run the program, the new file `out.txt` was created but it is empty.
Vscode doesn't show errors so I don't know where to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the `write` function completely writes that line from `fin` to `fout`, hence the last line in `fin` must be blank hence your output is blank as well. Try using the append feature to fix this `fout = open("out.txt", "a")`, or you can replace `fout.write` with `fout.writelines`

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  You might add a `print` statement in the loop, just to make sure it's running.

Comment: @GautamChettiar -- that's completely wrong.  Once the file is open, writes will always append.

Comment: My bad yea I just checked its working fine with me as well

Comment: This has nothing to do with VSCode or that you're running on macOS. Apart from the fact that you're not taking advantage of the work manager paradigm, your code will work providing file.txt exists in your current working directory and you have permission to create out.txt. Also, there's no reason to read the input file one line at a time unless it's massive and you have memory constraints

Comment: One possible other reason: the files that are read and written are not in the folder where they are expected. There might be an old file "out.txt"  lying around in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should always use context manager for IO.
2. `open` with `"t"` is not necessary since `t` stands for `text mode`, which is default.

```py
# main.py
with open("file.txt", "r") as fin, open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin.readlines(): # using for line in fin also works
        fout.write(line.replace("old", "new"))
```

```
❯ python3 main.py
❯ cat file.txt
test old
test                                                                                                                                            
❯ cat out.txt
test new
test
```

Comment: Also open with `"r"` is not necessary since `"r"` stands for `read mode`, which is default.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your input file is massive, then there's no reason to read it line by line. The following will suffice:

```
with open('file.txt') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
  fout.write(fin.read().replace('old', 'new'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem in your code that you only open the file without reading it correctly:

```
fin = open("file.txt", "rt")
data = fin.read(4)    # read the first 4 characters
data = fin.read()     # read till end of file
data = fin.readline() # read one line of the file at current cursor
data = fin.readlines() # read till end of file line by line and return it in list
```

It's recommended to put opening, reading, writing file operations between `try except` block in case any exception during reading file and writing to it happened, you can either read the file line by line using for loop with `open()` method or using `read(), readline()` methods:

```
try:
   fin = open("file.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8')
   #output file to write the result to
   fout = open("out.txt", "w")
   for line in fin:
      # read replace the string and write to output file
      fout.write(line.replace('old', 'new'))
except Exception as e:
   print("Error", e, "occurred.")
finally:
   fin.close()
   fout.close()
```

**Note:** when working with files in text mode, it is highly recommended to specify the encoding type.

For more info about I/O file operations check [reference](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation).